# Object to Json with Gson | ANDROID

Tags: java, android, json

I need to convert this object to a Json String but if the Object is declared into the MainActivity Class I cant. If i declared it into the function, it works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class Boton implements Serializable{
    public Button bt;
    public String path;
    public String fname;
    /*Boton(Button bt, String path, String fname){
        this.bt = bt;
        this.path = path;
        this.fname = fname;
    }*/
}
Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        load_bts();
}

public void load_bts(){
        Button bt = new Button(this);
        Boton cbt = new Boton();
        cbt.bt = bt;
        cbt.path = "QUESO";
        cbt.fname = "";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(cbt);
}
```

if I do this, The app works:

```
public void load_bts() {
    class Boton implements Serializable {
        public Button bt;
        public String path;
        public String fname;
    }
    Button bt = new Button(this);
    Boton cbt = new Boton();
    cbt.bt = bt;
    cbt.path = "QUESO";
    cbt.fname = "";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(cbt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize a Button. Both ways doesn't work. Even with your second method, the json variable is null.

Comment: How can i "save" a class with a button? Do u know?

Answer (score 0):

**Button in android is not serializable.**

But you could serialize the metadata(properties) of button, such as textsize,textcolor,etc.
then use these data when create button.